# The 'this' keyword in Unity3D scripts (c# script, JavaScript)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm confused that:

### CODE (CS01.cs)

The script is attached to a simple Cube object.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CS01 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log (this); //--> Cube(CS01)
        Debug.Log (this.GetType()); //--> CS01
        Debug.Log (this.GetType() == typeof(UnityEngine.GameObject)); //--> False
        Debug.Log (this == gameObject); //--> False
        Debug.Log (this.name); //--> Cube
        Debug.Log (gameObject.name); //--> Cube
        this.name = "Hello"; // --> Will get the gameObject's name changed to 'Hello'
        Debug.Log (gameObject.name); //--> Hello
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

1> Will `CS01` be an script object right?

> **DOC**: Scripting inside Unity consists of attaching custom script
>   objects called behaviours to game objects.

2> In `Component` object, variables like transform, renderer, rigidbody are referenced to the components of `gameObject` this `Component` attached to. So in the script, `this.renderer.material.color = Color.red;` is equivalent to `this.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red`. However, the description of variable `name` in the document `name: The name of the object.` only tells it's the name of the object. 
3> So, how to understand the code above? Does the variable `name` also return the `name` of the gameObject this script attached to? 
4> `this` means the script object but not the gameObject the script attached to, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attach `CS01` to a game object in the scene and this game object will be loaded, you will have one instance of each. During the construction of `CS01` before `Awake` and `OnEnable` are called, all properties like `gameObject`, `tranform`, `name`, etc. are initialised. Most of them will get a reference to the parent's properties if they are refering to an object.

`string` class is somewhat special in C# or java and behaves rather like a `struct` - it will be *kind of copied*. In detail: `CS01.name` (which is inherited from `Unity.Object`) will get the game object's name. As long as they have both the same name, both variables point to the same place in memory. When you change CS01's name, a new `string` instance will be created internally and be initialised with the text you assign to it. Thus the original i.e. name property of game object will remain unchanged.

1. Yes
2. Most components have properties that refer to the `GameObject` properties, kind of shortcut
3. Like in 2. `name` is defined in base class `Object`. `GameObject` and `MonoBehaviour` both are derived from `Unity.Object`.
4. Exactly, this is the class where you writing it in the code

Comment: But according to my understanding, in the script `this` is an instant of `CS01` which derived from `MonoBehaviour`, so, if I changed the `name`, it will not affect the `gameObject` it attached to. The relationship between `Cube` and `CS01` should be combination.

Comment: name is a property of MonoBehavior that actually set/get the GameObject name. A shortcut as said by Kay. So actually this.name and gameObject.name points to the same value.