# Does 'this' refer to gameObject or class or the name of the c# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, this, persistent, gameobject

I was trying to understand how to implement DontDestroyOnLoad for Unity3D and I came across this article: https://honkbarkstudios.com/developer-blog/dontdestroyonload-tutorial/

The article, written by Christian Engvall, provides the following code as a tutorial:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MusicController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static MusicController Instance;

    void Awake() 
    {
        this.InstantiateController();
    }

    private void InstantiateController() {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }
        else if(this != Instance) {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Further information: Engvall created a gameObject named MusicController and attached an audio source to it. He also attached a C# script also called MusicController. The script then contains a public static variable of type, MusicController, into which he dragged the gameObject. The goal of the code is to allow the audio to play unabated across scenes, i.e. don't destroy the gameObject containing the audio source as new scenes load.

I am confused whether 'this' refers to the gameObject or the MusicController class. When I read `this.InstantiateController();` it seems that 'this' must be the MusicController public class. However, down below here

```
if(Instance == null)
{
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
else if(this != Instance) {
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

it seems that 'this' must refer to the gameObject that is linked to the MusicController public static variable named Instance.

So I'm confused. Which is it? Or is it something else entirely?

I tried reading this previous stack overflow post from 6 years ago but am unfortunately still confused.
[The 'this' keyword in Unity3D scripts (c# script, JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828217/the-this-keyword-in-unity3d-scripts-c-script-javascript)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is making a simple singleton of the MusicComponent.

`this` always refers to the instance of a class. So, in this case, it's the instance of a `MusicController`.

`this.gameObject` just means you're getting the `gameObject` that's attached to the `MusicController`.

`Instance` is static and that means there will only ever be a single "instance" pinned to some place in memory. Every instance of `MusicComponent` will have access to the that single "instance" object. So, in the method you highlighted:

```
//I'm an instance of MusicComponent and I want to see if
//some other instance exists. If there's another music component already
//then Instance will NOT be null
if(Instance == null)
{
    //Now I know I'm the only MusicComponent created so I'll set this static property to me
    //This lets any new MusicComponents created know that there is already one alive
    //and they should not stay alive
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
else if(this != Instance) {
    //Turns out, I'm not the first instance of MusicComponent created because
    //because another one has already set themselves to static property
    //I know this but my pointer (this) isn't the same as the pointer set to the 
    //Instance static property
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

I hope that clears some of it up.

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful. I guess I'm having trouble conceptualizing setting an instance of a class to the class itself. I admit to not being very experienced but I would have thought that an instance could only be set to an instance. It's much easier for me to conceptualize 'this.InstantiateController()' than 'Instance = this'  ...if that makes any sense. But your explanation was very helpful and I think it's enough for me to carry on at least. Thank you.

Comment: @Siggytron A static property means that all instances of that class share the same property. So, when musicComponent1 sets `Instance = this` then musicComponent2 can see that `Instance` points to musicComponent1. I admit, when you're starting out, it's a little tricky to wrap your head around. But keep up the good work; you're doing well.

Answer (score 0):

This is like saying myself.

In unity scripts of components, it is referring to the class instance you are in.